# IBM Mobile First Platform not taking the JquerMobile folder in Ubuntu Operating System

Tags: jquery, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

We are going to developing the Hybrid mobile application using JqueryMobile in IBM Mobile First Platform 7.1,Java 8, eclipse-jee-luna-SR2 4.2.2 and Jquery

> When i am creating the application in that time i am trying to plugin
>   the JqueryMobile it is successfully adding but not generating the
>   Jquery folder in the application and also not able see the Jquery
>   widgets in the Palette.
>
> Above the process i total done it in Ubuntu 14..4 LTS. But i follow
>   the same process in windows 10 operating system it will showing the Jquery widgets and
>   also JqueryMobile folder created.

what is happening i am not able to understanding what is the difference just i tested in windows it's working but in the Ubuntu Not working

Please anyone suggested me why happening like this all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem in the jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js that didn't exist
in 1.4.0 and was fixed in 1.4.2.

They are using the "default" reserved keyword as identifier at line 3195.
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqm-1-4-1-using-default-as-property-name-causes-syntax-error-on-some-platforms

And defect status is:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/7119

Upgrade the jQuery mobile to 1.4.2, then it will be resolved.
They renamed the "default" to "defaultDuration"